# PySide2 new Signal and Slot connection

Tags: python, qt, pyside

There was a recent update in PySide2 and now all of my apps are broken. I have code like this...

```
from PySide2.QtCore import *                                                   

class Saver(QObject):                                                                               

    doneSaving = Signal()                                                      

    def __init__(self, app, signaller, param, items):                             
        """Constructor"""                                                         
        super(Saver, self).__init__()                                             

        self.app = app                                                            
        self.param = param                                                        
        self.items = items                                                        

        sig = app.getSignaller(signaller)                                         
        help(sig.valueAvailable)                                                  
        sig.valueAvailable.connect(self.dataReceived)                                         

        self.saving = False
```

And it recently stopped working because apparently `QtCore.Signal()` no longer has an attribute called connect. I've looked through the docs but can't find anything.

**Does any one know the new syntax to connect signals and slots in PySide2?**

Comment: I just looked briefly through the [PySide's repository](https://code.qt.io/cgit/pyside/pyside.git/) and I cannot see anything tha changed `QtCore.Signal()` in a way that would break your code. Have you verified the class of `doneSaving`?

Answer (score 1):

I finally resolved this. I had jumped the gun in thinking that it was the API that had changed. My app is using Shiboken to wrap some C++ stuff and it was those shared objects which had changed.

After recompiling all the wrappers everything started working again.